# Feeding input to an interactive command line application

Tags: winapi, shell, powershell, scripting, automation

I'd like to feed inputs to a command line interface for Cisco AnyConnect `vpncli.exe` (v2.3) to automate its (re)connection.  It does not take username nor password as command line arguments, but reads those interactively from the user via the command line interface.

Problem is that piping input to `vpncli.exe` doesn't seem to work for the password. It works for everything except the password. So doing things like this doesn't work:

```
vpncli.exe < input.txt
type input.txt | vpncli.exe
```

The application just gets stuck at where it asks for the password.

Below is an example of normal (working) execution where the user enters the parameters:

[image: Example vpncli.exe run]

Notice how the password characters get transformed to `*`.

Using tools like AutoIt or AutoHotKey to send the inputs to a command prompt window works, but is clumsy and fragile (does not work if the tool can't get to the command prompt window for some reason).

Is there any way to send inputs to such interactive CLI application using PowerShell?

(Or using any other scripting language or some other means?)

Comment: Will this help - http://www.joshuasjohnson.com/how-to-script-a-login-for-a-cisco-vpn-client/

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal, unfortunately no, it's a different version of VPN client.

Comment: Try http://wasp.codeplex.com - try to send keystrokes to the console window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least two ways to read input in a Windows console application.

- `ReadConsole`: reads input either from keyboard or redirection ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
- `ReadConsoleInput`: reads only raw keystrokes ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

The `vpncli.exe` application uses `ReadConsoleInput` in order to read the password, that's way redirecting the password does not work. You can, though, use `WriteConsoleInput`. I have a small Python script that does exactly that:

```
import subprocess
import win32console

ANYCONNECT_BIN = 'c:\\Program Files\\Cisco\\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\\vpncli.exe'

def write_console_input(text):
  stdin = win32console.GetStdHandle(win32console.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
  ir = win32console.PyINPUT_RECORDType(win32console.KEY_EVENT)
  ir.KeyDown = True
  for ch in text:
    ir.Char = unicode(ch)
    stdin.WriteConsoleInput([ir])

def main():
  proc = subprocess.Popen([ANYCONNECT_BIN,'connect','VPN'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  proc.stdin.write('%s\n%s\n' % ('GROUP', 'USERNAME'))
  write_console_input('%s\n' % 'PASSWORD')
  ret = proc.wait()
  print ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Thanks, good info/ref and example. Altho I ended up using `ControlSend` with AHK to send keystrokes to the console window (which works fine even if window is minimized, etc).

Answer (score 11):

you need to create an usual text file like

connect myvpnhost
myloginname
mypassword

save it as myfile.dat (for example) and then call

"%ProgramFiles%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -s < myfile.dat

Comment: In the question I stated that exactly this does **not** work. Or are you saying that the `-s` flag makes it work? What does that flag do?

Comment: yes, -s flag simply expands the stdin (<) to the console. it works for me ideally for about a year

Comment: if you don't trust me, simply run vpncli.exe /? :-)

Comment: Using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 3.0.08057), the `-s` flag is no longer an option (thus this answer doesn't work), are there any other workarounds?

Comment: This flag seems to work in version 4.9