# Passing values to intermediate (runtime) input prompts of Windows command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a windows exe which displays some copyright information, connects to a server and then prompts for input of username and password.

So whenever I run this, I have to wait for the prompt to input username and password.
I generally type ahead the username, , password after the command starts displaying copyright information, but that is a crude way.

Is there a better way to pass parameters to a input prompt of windows command, in a batch file, so that i can avoid typing them always?

P.S. In Linux we do this using the << operator like this

```
linux_command <<delimiter
inputparamvalue1
inputparamvalue2
delimiter
```

linux_command will run and on first input prompt, it reads inputparamvalue1 and at next input prompt, it reads inputparamvalue2

In response to James, thanks for the advice on security. I will take care of that.

I tried to implement your solution but that did not work.

These are my files. Please see if you get any hint.

vpn.bat

```
@ echo off    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client\vpncli.exe" connect "mycompanyvpnsite.com"
```

login.txt

```
myusername  
mypassword
```

startvpn.bat

```
@ECHO OFF  
CALL vpn.bat < login.txt  
ECHO I'm back!
```

Result

```
D:\>startvpn.bat  
Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client (version 2.5.6005) .  

Copyright (c) 2004 - 2010 Cisco Systems, Inc.  
All Rights Reserved.  


  >> state: Disconnected  
  >> notice: Ready to connect.  
  >> registered with local VPN subsystem.  
  >> state: Disconnected  
  >> notice: Ready to connect.  
VPN>   >> contacting host (mycompanyvpnsite.com) for login information...  
  >> notice: Contacting mycompanyvpnsite.com.  
VPN>  
  >> Please enter your username and password.  

Username: [myusername] Password:
```

Username myusername which it is showing is cached from my previous manual logins. So it appears that this run did not take any values from the login.txt.
 If I had executed my vpn.bat alone without any params, i get prompt like this

```
VPN>  
  >> Please enter your username and password.  

Username: [myusername] <i press enter to take the cached value>  
Password: ******** <i enter password and press enter>
```

and it connects.

The vpn client does not have privilege to specify password on command line, that's why I am trying this way.

Comment: Try this: (echo inputparamvalue1 & echo inputparamvalue2) | command

Comment: @HarryJohnston, your solution is giving the same result as of James's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Feeding input to an interactive command line application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480056/feeding-input-to-an-interactive-command-line-application)

Comment: This is solved in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28048413/397331 using:
`vpncli.exe -s (...)`

Answer (score 2):

i've got a working code! It's similar to James K's but with a few bugs hammered out. Once again, I want to reiterate that this is rather insecure because it exposes your password in an unencrypted setting. that being said:

```
'Anyconnect login script
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' rather clunky way of selecting the correct directory - open to suggestion
oShell.Run "cmd /k cd %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Cisco & cd Cisco* & vpncli.exe connect MYCOMPANYVPN.COM"

' sleep of 100 neccessary or else it opens multiple cmd windows
Wscript.sleep 100

' activate correct window
oShell.AppActivate "Connect"

' optional ipsec Identifier used for multiple VPN profiles on the same server
'(if you don't have one, just comment this out)
oShell.SendKeys "IPSECID{ENTER}"

' Send Username and Password to Active Window.
oShell.SendKeys "USERNAME{ENTER}"
oShell.SendKeys "USERPASSSWORD{ENTER}"

oShell.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Saving your username and password in a file to automate login processes is a very bad idea and invalidates any security that requiring usernames and passwords supplies because anyone who get's electronic or physical access to your computer will have access to your plain-text username and password.

That said, in DOS / Windows Command Prompt you will need an extra file containing your username and password like so:

`LOGIN.TXT`

```
MyUserName
MyPassword
```

Then pipe that file into your command like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL Command_Or_Batch < login.txt
ECHO I'm back!
```

This will act just as if you were at the console and typed `MyUserName[ENTER]` `MyPassword[ENTER]`.

`login.txt` is just a plain vanilla text file, and does not need the `.txt` extension, or any extension at all for that matter.

The `CALL` statement is only necessary when launching another batch file, if you want it to, when finished, continue executing in the original calling batch file. Using `CALL` makes no difference when calling an executable (anything other than a batch file).

---

**EDIT:** As per your comments, I believe that you need to do this to get it to work:

```
@ echo off    
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client\vpncli.exe" connect "mycompanyvpnsite.com" < login.txt
```

In this case you redirect to your `vpncli.exe`, but I believe that this will have the side-effect of making `vpncli.exe` **ONLY** accept input from `login.txt`, and not from the keyboard at all until `vpncli.exe` exits. Meaning that you'll need to automate (store in `login.txt`) all the stuff you would normally need to type in. This should not be a problem unless you need to manually interact with `vpncli.exe` later on.

---

**EDIT:** Since `vpncli.exe` seems to be clearing the buffer before reading any keystrokes, I suggest that possibly using VBS might get you where you're wanting to go.

`VPN.VBS`
    'VBScript Example
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

```
WshShell.Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client\vpncli.exe connect mycompanyvpnsite.com"

' You need to know the name of the window, It should be in the upper left corner
' I'm guessing that it will be the filename of the executible
WshShell.AppActivate "vpncli.exe"

' Send Username and Password to Active Window.
WshShell.SendKeys "MyUserName{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "MyPassword{ENTER}"
```

But I can't be sure. I've had problems testing this, though I'm just bouncing back and forth between batch files and VBS scripts.

Though I do know if you replace the **WshShell.Run** and **WshShell.AppActivate** with the following two lines that...

```
WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad.exe"
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
```

...notepad will open and the following two lines will appear:

```
MyUserName
MyPassword
```

If this doesn't work for you, I'm thinking about deleting this answer entirely since it only contains suggestions that haven't worked.

Comment: please check my comments below posted as answer. The comment markup was insufficient to display my codes, so I had to use answer option.

Comment: @ChinniKrishna - I edited your follow-on into the question itself, which is where it really belongs. You might want to clean that up to fit the rest of your question, though.

Comment: Thanks Brad for not voting down. I will follow your advise.

Comment: James, I tried passing login.txt to vpncli directly, but the result is same.
It appears that vpncli is executing something like 'clear input buffer' when it is prompting for password. I suspected this after a trial of putting two lines - 1. ENTER and 2. y - in the login.txt. (vpncli expects a 'y' for a banner of terms after password before connecting). The result was - it probably took line 1 for user name, which made it use cached user name, stopped at password prompt, I manually entered password+ENTER and then it took the "y" from logn.txt and connected.

Comment: James, would the newline character in login.txt matter anyway? I create it in Notepad++ and on making non printable characters visible, I see it as 
myusername{CR}{LF}mypassword{CR}{LF}. I tried all the combinations with CR, LF individually and both. Result is same.

Comment: @ChinniKrishna: I have a feeling that you're right about `vpncli` clearing the buffer. As far as the CR+LF characters go I really don't know if their order matters, from the sound of your results, is sounds like it does not.