# How can the WriteConsoleInput function of a Windows console be accessed in Java?

Tags: java, winapi, processbuilder

I am trying to accomplish the exact same thing as this user:

[Feeding input to an interactive command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480056/feeding-input-to-an-interactive-command-line-application)

Except I need to do it in Java instead of Python. I create a process for vpncli.exe using ProcessBuilder and I am able to feed it the username through its OutputStream. This does not work for the password however. The solution of the above post indicates that vpncli.exe uses a different input method for the password, namely ReadConsoleInput instead of ReadInput. So my question is: How can I access the WriteConsoleInput function from java?