# Python - can't run subprocess .exe console app without "start" that waits for input

Tags: python, .net, windows, subprocess, console-application

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, search and tried many things and I still can't understand what needs to get done.

I have to automate the execution of this .NET console app named "GetData.exe".
I'm doing this with Python 3.5.2, using the subprocess module and on Windows 10.

Since the console app doesn't receive arguments, I have to send the intended input by stdin. And I completely understand by now how am I supposed to deal with stdin, stdout or stderr.

But what's failing it's simply executing the app, as executing it this way:

`exe = 'C:\........\GetData.exe' # pseudo path
 p = subprocess.run([exe], input=input_string, 
 universal_newlines=True, check=True)
 print(p)`

Outputs the following errors:

`at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
 at System.Console.get_WindowWidth()
 at GetData.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Googling this errors lead me to almost no relevant information regarding Python subprocess module.

And the subprocess.run returns this (on the print):
`CompletedProcess(args='C:\\Users\\......\\GetData.exe', returncode=3762504530)`

But, after some googling I found that typing "start cmd" being cmd the command I wanted to call, coupled with the argument `shell=True`, makes the console app window open like it does when I double-click on the .exe, or like when I call it from the command line:

`p = subprocess.run("start "+exe, input=input_string, universal_newlines=True, check=True)`

Makes it show this:
[image: start <cmd> execution]

And it keeps open waiting for my input while the rest of my python code execution finishes instead of at least while having the window open, reading my input from stdin...

I think it might be some fault with the console app that forces it to be executed within an open window... I've seen some questions regarding `creationflags` and `startupinfo,` and I've tried those with the underlying contructor Popen (of the newer subprocess.run method) but with no success.

Comment: I may be off here, but you said that your console app doesn't accept arguments...but you're trying to send it arguments?  If you need to communicate with it should you be calling the "cmd.exe" and passing input to that instead?

Comment: @Mike Indeed it doesn't accept arguments, but it does accept stdin that's what I'm trying to do. I think sending input arguments doesn't have to be through cmd.exe, it's a pipe that I can stream data... But that's the least of the problem as I can't even get it to properly execute automatically...

Comment: By default `start` has CMD call `CreateProcess` with the  `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` creation flag, which in this case causes the standard handles for the GetData.exe process to be reset to console buffer handles. That happens because CMD doesn't use the `STARTUPINFO` standard handles, unlike Python `subprocess`.

Comment: Apparently GetData.exe needs the `StandardInput` handle to be a console input buffer. In that case you'll have to resort to the more extreme measure of calling the console API `WriteConsoleInput` function.

Comment: @eryksun I was thinking the same. Those C# / Microsoft console exes are a pain.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you. I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791101/6245942, and I think now I have to use the win32console module right?

Comment: Yes, that will work if you're ok with depending on PyWin32. Otherwise you can use ctypes, but it's more work.

Comment: I think PyWin32 might do what I need. Shall I still call the subprocess with "start" or just the exe?

Comment: Run the executable directly, not via CMD, but don't redirect `StandardInput`. Are you running as a console process? If you are, then the child will inherit your console. If not, you'll need to call `win32api.SetStdHandle(win32console.STD_INPUT_HANDLE, None)` and then `win32console.AttachConsole(p.pid)` beforehand. This will attach to the child's console and ensure your `StandardInput` handle gets reset to a handle for the console's input buffer. Then after writing to the input buffer, if you had to attach you should detach via `win32console.FreeConsole()`.

Comment: @eryksun Thank you so much. Now, I'm getting Acess Denied when I try to AttachConsole, what should I do?

Comment: Like I said, only call `AttachConsole` if you're *not* already attached to a console when you create the child process. python.exe is a console application, which automatically inherits or allocates a console unless run as a `DETACHED_PROCESSS`. pythonw.exe is a GUI application, which doesn't automatically have a console. And an embedded or frozen executable is up to you.

Comment: @eryksun understood. Without Attaching, I'm getting this weird error, it doesn't show the error Type, only tells me that it is on `stdin.WriteConsoleInput([ir])`...